# Running django project on apache in ubuntu

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I want to run my django project on apache server. I found ton of tutorial to run django project on apache but in virtualenv.  But I dont want to use virtualenv. I have installed apache2 and got it running fine. I installed mod_wsgi. Now what I need to do?

I am doing this whole thing in ubuntu/local environment.

Can any one help me???

Comment: Your next step is likely to make sure all the apache modules you need are enabled and configure a virtualhost. However, this is a bit off topic for stackoverflow. You'll probably get a better response if you post the question on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Why do you have a problem.. [django deployment section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) clearly explains how to set it up, just use global `site-packages` location instead of the `virtualenv` one..

Comment: yup...Now I able to do this.....I found 2 ways and both working...

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure apache's virtual host configure file in /etc/apache/site-available (in case of Ubuntu) and give the path of your wsgi web application
here it is [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) for deployment of Django

these links will help you

http://www.gaggl.com/2013/11/ubuntu-13-10-based-pythondjangowsgi-setup/

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-django-with-mod_wsgi-and-apache-with-a-virtualenv-python-environment-on-a-debian-vps

Comment: Do you know any document for run django in Centos vps ? (Or youtube tutorial) @alok-singh-mahor