# Install Django project on Ubuntu distant server

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to install my `Django project` from my MacOSX localhost to an ubuntu distant server. I'm getting a problem with Apache in order to display my project.

This is some steps that I've done :

- Create an ubuntu distant server with IP adress : 172.30.10.58
- Copy/Paste my Django project to /var/www/html/
- Install Apache2
- Install all Django modules (it's ok because if I run `python manage.py runserver`, I don't get error)

I followed some tutorials :

- [Running django project on apache in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121270/running-django-project-on-apache-in-ubuntu)

So my **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-defaut.conf** looks like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/etat_civil/


        Alias /static/ /var/www/html/etat_civil/BirthCertificate/static/
        Alias /uploads/ /secure_dir/uploads/

        WSGIDaemonProcess daemon-etat_civil user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 maximum-requests=1 threads=1 inactivity-timeout=6
        WSGIProcessGroup daemon-etat_civil
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/etat_civil/Etat_civil/wsgi.py

        <Directory /var/www/html/etat_civil/Etat_civil>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Location "/uploads/">
                SetHandler None
        </Location>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/monprojet.error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mystock.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Then, I run : `python manage.py runserver`

I'm getting :

```
ec@srvEC:/var/www/html/etat_civil$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DIRS.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
January 31, 2017 - 09:25:12
Django version 1.10.5, using settings 'Etat_civil.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

But when I run in my browser : `http://172.30.10.58` or something else, I get :

[image]

or

[image]

Could you help me to get a working Django project please ?

Thank you

**EDIT :**

Log files :

```
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052359 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913] mod_wsgi (pid=7731): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/etat_civil/Etat_civil/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052493 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913] mod_wsgi (pid=7731): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/etat_civil/Etat_civil/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052529 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052560 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913]   File "/var/www/html/etat_civil/Etat_civil/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052660 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052677 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052727 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052744 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052793 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052807 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052900 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913]     self._setup(name)
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052917 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052940 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052951 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052968 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.052979 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.053042 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913]     __import__(name)
[Tue Jan 31 11:12:47.053070 2017] [:error] [pid 7731] [remote 172.30.10.54:52913] ImportError: No module named Etat_civil.settings
```

And tree architecture :

```
.
├── etat_civil
│   ├── Accueil
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── admin.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   │   └── Base.css
│   │   │   └── images
│   │   │       ├── admin.png
│   │   │       ├── employé.png
│   │   │       ├── logo.png
│   │   │       ├── maire.png
│   │   │       ├── officier.png
│   │   │       └── visiteur.png
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── Accueil.html
│   │   ├── templatetags
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── user_tags.py
│   │   │   └── user_tags.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── urls.pyc
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── views.pyc
│   ├── BirthCertificate
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── admin.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── forms.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── countries.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── forms.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── sexe.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   │   └── BC_base.css
│   │   │   └── images
│   │   │       └── logo.jpeg
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── BC_accueil.html
│   │   │   ├── BC_form.html
│   │   │   ├── BC_PDF.html
│   │   │   ├── BC_preview.html
│   │   │   ├── BC_raw2.html
│   │   │   ├── BC_raw.html
│   │   │   ├── BC_resume.html
│   │   │   └── Not_Found.html
│   │   ├── templatetags
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── user_tags.py
│   │   │   └── user_tags.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── urls.pyc
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── views.pyc
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── Etat_civil
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── settings.pyc
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   │   └── BC_base.css
│   │   │   └── images
│   │   │       ├── chantier.jpeg
│   │   │       ├── chantier.png
│   │   │       └── logo.png
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── urls.pyc
│   │   ├── wsgi.py
│   │   └── wsgi.pyc
│   ├── Identity
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── admin.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── forms.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── countries.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── forms.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── sexe.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   │   └── Base.css
│   │   │   └── images
│   │   │       └── logo.png
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── delete.html
│   │   │   ├── edit.html
│   │   │   ├── form_Identity.html
│   │   │   ├── Identity_home.html
│   │   │   ├── identity_resume.html
│   │   │   ├── preview.html
│   │   │   └── resume.html
│   │   ├── templatetags
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── user_tags.py
│   │   │   └── user_tags.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── urls.pyc
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── views.pyc
│   ├── log
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── admin.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── forms.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   └── connexion.html
│   │   ├── templatetags
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── user_tags.py
│   │   │   └── user_tags.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── urls.pyc
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── views.pyc
│   ├── Mairie
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── admin.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── forms.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── models.pyc
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── countries.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── forms.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── models.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── sexe.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   ├── css
│   │   │   │   └── Base.css
│   │   │   └── images
│   │   │       └── logo.png
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   │   ├── Mairie_form.html
│   │   │   ├── Mairie_home.html
│   │   │   └── Mairie_Resume.html
│   │   ├── templatetags
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   │   ├── user_tags.py
│   │   │   └── user_tags.pyc
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── urls.pyc
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   └── views.pyc
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── media
│   │   └── logo.jpeg
│   ├── static
│   │   └── images
│   └── templates
│       ├── Base_Accueil.html
│       ├── Base_BirthCertificate.html
│       ├── Base_Identity.html
│       ├── Base_Mairie.html
│       └── Base_Not_Found.html
├── index.html
└── Individus
```

Comment: what errors do you have in apache log files?

Comment: You're telling apache's config file that the site is etat_civil.com, but you're taking your browser to `http://172.30.10.58`.  Have you set up the DNS routing and everything?  `A` and `CNAME` and such?

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov Very strange, log file is empty in `/var/log/apache2/monprojet.error.log`

Comment: @coralvanda You're right, I deleted both lines about ServerName and ServerAlias because I don't want set up the DNS routing for the moment ^^

Comment: @Andro is your Apache default config enabled?

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov I checked my sites-enabled from Apache2. I made `sudo a2ensite 000-defaut.conf` so I assume that Apache is ok ? I'm really new with Apache and hosted machines, not really my job :/

Comment: @Andro it should be ok, but I am wondering if you have apache error it should be shown in logs. Try to change add "LogLevel warn" before logs paths. Restart apache and have a look if there are any errors

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov I edited my question with log files ;)

Comment: @Andro ok. it shows that it cannot find settings. It means that the path should be DocumentRoot /var/www/html/etat_civil/etat_civil/

Comment: Why are you running runserver as well as Apache? That makes no sense. Apache/mod_wsgi *replaces* the dev server.

Comment: @A It doesn't work.
@DanielRoseman I'm sorry, I don't what I have to do :/ First time I'm making this kind of things

Comment: @Andro it is one of the errors you have. Most probably there are others. What is there in logs after you have changed the path?

Comment: I have to modify this file : `httpd.conf ` but I don't have it in /etc/apache2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: @Andro you don't have it because you are using apache2

Comment: What you do is *not run manage.py runserver*.

Comment: I tried lots of things and it works now with this tutorial `https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/.

I just don't have css stylesheet to admin part. Necessary to open a new question or in this one ?

Answer (score 0):

Import mod_wsgi module in your apache configuration file

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-defaut.conf**